# Running a mono app with the Cray aprun command

Tags: c#, mono, parallel-processing, cray

I've been able to get a C# mono program to run on my Cray machine by making a simple batch script and passing that to the aprun command. I'm experimenting with a very small file and I'm getting the output I'd expect... what I'm wondering is if anyone who has more experience would be so kind as to tell me if this is actually making use of the aprun command like a C/C++/Fortran compiled program would? i.e. Am I managing to get the program to run on several cores but without any real benefit? Or if I'm managing to run on multiple cores then is this essentially all that aprun does anyway? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aprun is a task scheduling program that performs system resource allocation. As such, if the program being run by the aprun command has been distributed to the specified number of cores and/or nodes then the aprun command has successfully completed (it may continue to monitor system resource usage and timing unless additional options are specified) and any further use of that distribution of the program over cores and nodes must be handled by the internal logic thereof (e.g. implementing MPI or OpenMP).